# How to determine a execution time of a PHP, jQuery, AJAX script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**In 1st condition :**

I am passing values by using jQuery AJAX to a PHP file named email.php. Now I want that script to be executed up to 20 secs then after 20 secs it should throw an error that max execution time reached so that I can execute something through jQuery AJAX via getting the response.

**In 2nd Condition**

I want to determine the execution time of a jQuery code. Ex: if I have got some value through fields and I have sent to the server, somehow if the server does not respond then I want the script execution time, if the script has executed for more than 20 secs then I will terminate that process and display an error message of network error!

Comment: You are asking 2 different things, please separate it into 2 questions. Moreover Stackoverflow is not a place to have code generated to your specifications: you should explain what you have tried so far, show us the code you have written and ask where you are having trouble. Otherwhise your question will be closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Some links that may help you :

- PHP
  [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

[microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) could also help you.

- Javascript
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now